# Share status Facebook (objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, sdk

Is there a way for my users to share a facebook status in my app without authorizing? I have the ID to the status. The Facebook app should open and than ask the user if she/he wats to share the status? Is there a way to make the “share” say “XXX, shared via APP”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, There is no way to bypass the authorization process.

Imagine if you could. Every app you download would have the ability to spam a users wall. Facebook's API prohibits anything from being shared without authorization in order to cut down on this amount of spam.